# Play 3d Audio from ImageAnchor in SceneKit

Tags: augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I am assuming a Reality Composer file when imported into Xcode will not have the 3d audio controls I would like available in SceneKit.

So I am assuming I need to add a `SCNAudioSource` to an `ARImageAnchor` or can I use the anchors from Reality Composer?

Answer (score 0):

Reality Composer scenes can be disassembled and managed with RealityKit API, not SceneKit's one. So, if you wanna add audio to a scene made in Reality Composer, just implement RealityKit's [AudioResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/audioresource) class that can be played by any entity.

Here's an example of [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230335/cant-load-audio-using-audiofileresource-loadnamed-type-method).